# How to remap backward-delete and help command while using Emacs from a terminal emulator?

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows, term

I was using Emacs on CentOS 7 from the MobaXterm terminal on Windows 7, but the backspace key instead of backward-deleting a character invokes the prefix command `C-h`. According to [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceKey), I tried to put the following lines in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h") 'delete-backward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-?") 'help-command)
```

It does make the backspace act normally, but I couldn't invoke `C-h` by typing either `Ctrl-Shift-/` or `Ctrl-h`, or find anywhere to invoke it. Did I miss anything? Is it possible to let both backspace and `Ctrl-h` act as usual, that is, backspace doing backward-delete and `Ctrl-h` doing `C-h` help command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Emacs manual, node [DEL Does Not Delete](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html):

> On a text terminal, if you find that `<BACKSPACE>` prompts for a Help
>   command, like `Control-h`, instead of deleting a character, it means
>   that key is actually sending the `BS` character.  Emacs ought to be
>   treating `<BS>` as `<DEL>`, but it isn’t.
>
> In all of those cases, the immediate remedy is the same: use the
>   command `M-x normal-erase-is-backspace-mode`.  This toggles between the
>   two modes that Emacs supports for handling `<DEL>`, so if Emacs starts in
>   the wrong mode, this should switch to the right mode.  On a text
>   terminal, if you want to ask for help when `<BS>` is treated as `<DEL>`, use
>   `<F1>`; `C-?` may also work, if it sends character code 127.
>
> To fix the problem in every Emacs session, put one of the following
>   lines into your initialization file.  For the first
>   case above, where `<BACKSPACE>` deletes forwards instead of backwards, use
>   this line to make `<BACKSPACE>` act as `<DEL>`:
>
> ```
> (normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 0)
> ```
>
> For the other two cases, use this line:
>
> ```
> (normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)
> ```
>
> Another way to fix the problem for every Emacs session is to
>   customize the variable `normal-erase-is-backspace`: the value `t`
>   specifies the mode where `<BS>` or `<BACKSPACE>` is `<DEL>`, and `nil`
>   specifies the other mode.

I found this information in the Emacs manual using `i backspace S-TAB`, with [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles). In Icicles, `S-TAB` does "apropos"-style completion, which means that it checks here for `backspace` as a substring, not just as a prefix, of the completion candidates.

If you try `i backspace TAB` then you won't find any completion candidates, because the actual candidates you need to match are these, none of which begin with `backspace`:

```
<BACKSPACE> vs <DEL>
<DEL> vs <BACKSPACE>
c-electric-backspace
C-S-backspace 
normal-erase-is-backspace
normal-erase-is-backspace-mode
```

Comment: `(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)` works for me. Thanks!

Comment: (M-x normal-erase-is-backspace-mode) works to solve the "C+h = Suppr" problem for me !

Answer (score 2):

You can also uncheck the 'Backspace sends ^H' Terminal setting in MobaXterm Configuration page.