# Backspace triggers C-h in emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs

When I run a client in a terminal with `emacsclient -nw`, for some reason  <kbd>Backspace</kbd> triggers `C-h`. This doesn't happen with `emacs -nw` or with the client running in a window. In both cases, as expected, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the previous character. What can be the cause of this behavior and how can I fix that?

Comment: This may not be helpful, but I assume your terminal is interpreting backspace as C-h, as C-h is essentially delete character backwards in the terminal. This may not be an Emacs issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remap backward-delete and help command while using Emacs from a terminal emulator?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35524/how-to-remap-backward-delete-and-help-command-while-using-emacs-from-a-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html):

```
   On a text terminal, if you find that <BACKSPACE> prompts for a Help
command, like ‘Control-h’, instead of deleting a character, it means
that key is actually sending the ‘BS’ character.  Emacs ought to be
treating <BS> as <DEL>, but it isn’t.

   In all of those cases, the immediate remedy is the same: use the
command ‘M-x normal-erase-is-backspace-mode’.  This toggles between the
two modes that Emacs supports for handling <DEL>, so if Emacs starts in
the wrong mode, this should switch to the right mode.  On a text
terminal, if you want to ask for help when <BS> is treated as <DEL>, use
<F1> instead of ‘C-h’; ‘C-?’ may also work, if it sends character code
127.
```