# C-h invokes backspace

Tags: backspace

I have just started using XTerm as my terminal and have found that in Emacs C-h invokes backspace. C-h does not do this with other programs under XTerm so it seems like an Emacs specific problem, I previously had a problem with Esc and Alt being reversed, but this appeared with every program I ran under XTerm but that has now been fixed. Emacs work fine under LXTerminal.
Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: What does `stty -a` in that XTerm report as the `erase` character? (also: what version of Emacs are you using)

Comment: Does [If <DEL> Fails to Delete](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does BACKSPACE generate C-h?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78911/why-does-backspace-generate-c-h)

Comment: Or this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35524/how-to-remap-backward-delete-and-help-command-while-using-emacs-from-a-terminal

Comment: Just to make things clear, Emacs (29.1 on FreeBSD) works as expected under LXTerminal, other programs apart from Emacs work normally under XTerm.